# Unable to connect to docker postgres container with pytest

Tags: postgresql, docker, pytest

I am trying to use **pytest** to run some simple integration test against postgresql db. I have to use **python 2.7** so **testcontainers** are not the option.

my **conftest.py** looks like:

```py
import pytest
import docker  # this is a official system docker package


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def finalizer_function(container_id):
    container_id.stop()


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def db_init():
    """
    This db_init() method will start up docker container
    which will be used throughout all the tests and once
    all the tests are completed, containers will be
    automatically removed.

    :return:
    """
    client = docker.from_env()
    con_id = client.containers.run(
        image="postgres:9.6",
        name="postgres",
        detach=True,
        environment={
            'POSTGRES_DB': 'postgres',
            'POSTGRES_PASSWORD': 'test',
            'POSTGRES_USER': 'postgres',
        },
        remove=True,
        ports={"5432/tcp": 5432}
    )
    # yield con_id.stop()
```

and here is a very basic test I am not able to run **test_postgres.py**:

```py
import docker
import socket
import psycopg2
from postgres import Postgres


def test_connection_to_db(db_init):
    """

    :param db_init:
    :return:
    """
    print(socket.gethostname())
    dbo = Postgres(
        default_dbuser='postgres',
        default_db='postgres',
        host='127.0.0.1',
        password='test',
        port='5432'
    )

    _superuser = 'userx'
    dbo.create_user(user=_superuser, password='start123', superuser=True)
```

consider that `from postgres import Postgres` is my custom **postgres**
module which works with no problem.

```
PYTHONPATH=lib pytest -s -vv tests/test_postgres.py


...
E       OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
E               This probably means the server terminated abnormally
E               before or while processing the request.
```

However, when I start docker container by using **fixture** *db_init*
and I try to connect to this container with **psql** I can connect to db with no problem:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres -d postgres 
Password for user postgres: 
psql (10.6, server 9.6.12)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Please advise, Iam sure that there is just a silly mistake.

Thx

Comment: Can you provide postgres log after trying to execute the python script again ? might be an authentication issue

Comment: well this is a test container running during test and gets torn down but I have slightly adjusted my test to use pure psycopg2

```
import psycopg2

def test_connection_to_db(db_init):
    """

    :param db_init:
    :return:
    """
    con = psycopg2.connect(
        dbname='postgres',
        user='postgres',
        password='test',
        port=5432,
        host='127.0.0.1'
    )
    con.autocommit = True

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE DATABASE testdb;")
```

Comment: and when I run this test in debug mode, database gets created, but TEST will fail so what is wrong with pytest

Comment: I just figured out that the problem is in my conftest.py file 100% but I can't figure out what is the correct one.

Comment: Can you provide me with a repository contains a sample with instructions so i can test it ?